# JavaScript Послать бинарные данные

Tags: firefox-extension, javascript

Написал плагин для firefox, который ловит http-on-examine-response и перехватывает через TracingListener ответ от сервера. В итоге у меня получается массив receivedData = []; Я делал:

```
var responseSource = this.receivedData.join();
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("POST", "http://...", true);
req.send(responseSource);
```

Перехватывал ответ пожатый deflate, мне приходили побитые данные. Добавил заворачивание в base64, заработало отлично, но сейчас обнаружилось, что все равно бьется на больших объемах данных. Как написать код, чтобы я получал данные без всяких модификаций?

UPD: Код http://paste.org.ru/?9pfgt6

Comment: content type выставляете сервером ?

Comment: Сервер апач, сам ставит.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data

Comment: Читал, доходит плохо. Добавил исходный код. Как массив receivedData[] преобразовать в ArrayBuffer? У меня большое подозрение, что бинарные данные ломаются в процессе преобразования данных. Но где именно и как это исправить не понимаю.

Comment: а что кстати значит "данные ломаются" ? у вас там картинка или что ? может вы их просто выводите неправильно ?

Comment: Там JSON завернутый в gzip. И периодически длинные перехваченные данные оказываются битыми. С ощутимой закономерностью. Написал скрипт на php в который передаю данные http://pastebin.com/WRhHhMju . То есть проверяю уже двумя способами. Картина не меняется. Плагин можно тестировать например на этом https://vk.com/game_zombie_farm . Могу дать ссылку на готовый плагин. Хочу уже решить эту проблему.